# Python - catch exception of called method only

Tags: python, exception

It occurred to me, that you may want to catch an exception and do something, only if the called method raises some specific exception, but not if some lower method raises the same exception (because you only are ready to handle the top one). Consider the following:

```
def a():
    raise ValueError('raised by a')

def b():
    a()
    # Some other processing is done, which raises ValueError
    raise ValueError('raised by b')

def c():
    try:
        b()
    except ValueError as e:
        print "got the exception"
        print e
```

In this scenario, `c` "knows" that `b` may raise a `ValueError` and wants to do something with it. But it doesn't know what to do with other cases of `ValueError`... and sadly it will catch them.

```
>>> c()
got the exception
raised by a
```

Is there a way to handle this situation?

Feel free to criticize the approach too ;-) Maybe it's not a very clean approach, trying to handle just the top exception. And perhaps `b` should only raise a non-built-in exception...

Comment: Raise custom errors rather than default errors.

Comment: In `b()`, `try: a()` and do whatever you want here before processing further.